# Connect Android to RambO (Reprap) via USB

Tags: android, usb

Hy Guys
i try to connect my Rambo Board (http://reprap.org/wiki/Rambo) with android using https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/. The app allready starts when i plug in the usb port, but i cant open the device.
The testoutput of the vendor id and product id is right but "UsbSerialProber.acquire(mUsbManager, device);" returns null?
what can i do?

My App Works with an Arduino.

Thank you 
Markus

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Markus K hinzugefügt um device zu finden
    mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList(); 
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    mTitleTextView.setText(mTitleTextView.getText()+""+ deviceList.size()+"Geräte gefunden");
    UsbDevice device=null;
    while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
        device = deviceIterator.next();
        mTitleTextView.setText(mTitleTextView.getText()+ device.getDeviceName()+" vendorid: "+device.getVendorId()+"  productid"+device.getProductId());

        //abfrage auf richtige vendor id!!


    }



    mSerialDevice = UsbSerialProber.acquire(mUsbManager, device);

    mTitleTextView.setText(mTitleTextView.getText()+ "Resumed, mSerialDevice=" + mSerialDevice);
    if (mSerialDevice == null) {
        mTitleTextView.setText(mTitleTextView.getText()+ "No serial device.");
    } else {
```

Comment: Are you sure your particular Android device supports Android USB host mode? Many Android devices only support "USB peripheral mode", and it's not possible for two USB peripherals to directly communicate over a USB cable. USB requires one end to be host, and the other end to be peripheral.

Comment: The [Reproid](http://reprap.org/wiki/Reproid) page has links to open-source code for communicating between Android and a RepRap. Would any of them work for you?

Comment: Hi. Did you managed to solve this? I've been facing a similar situation.